# Prove that $R/f^{-1}(I') $ is isomorph with a subring of $R'/I'$ for the ringhomomorhism $f:R \to R'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm making exercises to prepare for my ring theory exam:

> Prove that $R/f^{-1}(I')$ is isomorph with a subring of  $R'/I'$ for the ringhomomorhism $f:R \to R'$

I already proved that $f^{-1}(I')$ is an ideal. I was thinking about something like:

Consider the map $R → R'→R'/I'$. If $ x\in R'/I'$ and $x=0$. Then $x\in I'$. Then $x\in f^{-1}(I')$.

And if $x\in f^{-1}(I)$ then $f(x) \in I$. Then $f(x) = 0$ modulo $I$.

But I think I'm doing something wrong as they ask an isomorphism with a subring of $R'/I'$.

Comment: If $x\in R'/I'$, it's not possible that $x\in f^{-1}(I')$, in general.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g\colon R\to R'/I'$ as you did; what is $\ker g$? Recall that 
$$
g(x)=f(x)+I'
$$
so $g(x)=0+I'$ if and only if $f(x)\in\dots$

Next use the homomorphism theorem.

Comment: If $g(x)=0+I'$. Then $f(x) \in I'$. Then $x \in f^{-1}(I')$.

Comment: If $x \in f^{-1}(I')$ then $f(x) \in I'$ then $g(x)=0+I'$.

Comment: Or, you not sure if $f$ is surjective. Is that why you need a subring ?

Comment: @Kasper Yes: $\ker g=f^{-1}(I')$ and so, by the homomorphism theorem, $g$ induces an injective homomorphism $R/f^{-1}(I')\to R'/I'$.